# Java String HashCode of n digits?

Tags: java, string, hashcode

I'm trying to get an ID from a String in Java, and I thought I would use hashcode (Yeah, two strings can have the same hashcode but I can live with that small probability). I want this ID to have a max of 4 digits. Is that possible?

This is the String default hashCode implementation:

```
public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;
    if (h == 0 && value.length > 0) {
        char val[] = value;

        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            h = 31 * h + val[i];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

Can I override it to produce a hash with 4 digits?

Comment: `return h % 10000`; should work

Comment: Just like you can have any number represented in 4 digits.  The remainder.

Comment: Sure, you can `@Override` any inherited method that is not final nor private. However, what is the meaning of reducing the length of the hash code to 4 digits?

Comment: First four digits? Last four digits? How do you want to choose the digits?

Comment: So you want to create an hash code of only 4 digits of a string? You now that the probability of collisions are higher?

Comment: How many of these are you going to produce? Even assuming the original hash codes are unique, you'll get collisions pretty quickly if you've only got 10,000 possible IDs.

Comment: What are you using this ID for?

Comment: @Nikolas You can't extend String.

Comment: @IlyaBursov except `h` can be negative…

Comment: @Holger yep, depending on how it is used later op could use abs

Comment: @IlyaBursov Unless it's `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: @shmosel it cannot be min value after modulo

Answer (score 1):

One simple trick is to just take the last four digits:

```
private static int myHash(String s) {
    return s.hashCode() % 10000;
}
```

**EDIT:**

As @Holger commented, `hashCode()` may return a negative value. If the requirement is to return a positive four-digit integer, you could take the absolute value:

```
private static int myHash(String s) {
    return Math.abs(s.hashCode() % 10000);
}
```

Comment: Why the  `static`?

Comment: @Nikolas why not?

Comment: Of course, you now only have 10,000 has code values, so the probability of collision is much higher than before,

Comment: @Mureinik: You shouldn't use a `static` method unless you have a very specific reason. So why the `static`?

Comment: @Nikolas His reason was to answer the question ;) He is not really using this on any of his production code.

Comment: @gtgaxiola: That's why I ask "why `static`"? :D I could answer with `public default int` method which makes no sense. Btw. the OP's sample code has no `static` inside nor asked for it. So I wonder as twice as more.

Comment: @Nikolas again - why not? You're not using any instance member here, so why push the `this` pointer needlessly in the stack?

Comment: @Nikolas The OP's code example is an instance method because [it's the JDK source code for `String.hashCode`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#l1439). (`String` is a final class, so we aren't talking about extending and overriding `hashCode`, nor should we ever override `hashCode` like this even in cases where we *can*, because of the Liskov Substitution Principle and contractual obligations in general.) With respect, your criticism doesn't make much sense. Utility methods like this are usually static.

Comment: @Mureinik: Weren't Mureinik supposed to answer me that? I see you defend his answer more than himself.